# check spaces using ascii code

Tags: java, char, ascii

I'm trying to remove spaces from a file while reading it. I do this by checking the ascii code of the char .. if it is not 127 (space) then print it out.

What is a better way to think of it?
or how to fix it this way?

```
private FileInputStream sc;
private static char input;

public void openFile(){
try{
    sc = new FileInputStream(new File ("D:\\Empty.txt"));
    input = (char) sc.read();
    if(input != 127){
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ParsingStrings ps = new ParsingStrings();
    ps.openFile();

}
```

Comment: ASCII 127 is `DEL`, a Space is 32.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a character stream such as FileReader wrapped in a BufferedReader because it reads character by character. I suspect that you will have some issues reading a byte and casting as a character the way you are doing it.

```
    String s;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
    while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (c != ' ') {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `(c = in.read()) != null` returns (cannot convert from int to char)

Comment: did you declare c as char?

Comment: Yes, isn't it supposed to be a char?

Comment: Yes. Sorry about that. I modified the solution a bit. Now it reads a line of text at a time and processes each line one char at a time. Tested. Works.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you make it much clearer (and obviously correct) by using a char literal?

```
if (input != ' ')
```

Also, Streams must be used to read binary data. To read text, you should use a Reader. Read the [Java IO tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html).

And of course, your method shouldn't eat exceptions like that. It should throw them, or at least wrap them in another exception and throw this exception.

Finally, the Reader should be a local variable of the `openFile()` method and not a field. And it should be closed in a finally block, or by using the Java 7's try-with-resources construct.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII space is 32, 127 is DEL. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. If you want to remove spaces from input, take a look at the [`FilterInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) class. Override the `read()` method: if it reads a space character, let it read one character further.
2. If you want to remove spaces from output, take a look at the [`FilterOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html) class. Override the `write(int)` method: if it is called to write a space character, let it do nothing.

In your particular case, I'd opt for the latter option, as I think it's a bit easier to implement, but the choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Use of a BufferedReader and InputStreamReader would help you.
This way you can using the .readLine() to read in each line in the file and then use .charAt() to read each character from that line.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
sc = new FileInputStream(new File ("D:\\Empty.txt"));

while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    input = sc.nextLine().replace(" ","");
    System.out.println(input);
}
```

I think instead of checking only one character you want to remove space from whole file and print it...yes?